# show desktop not Home

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, home-directory

I have my computer with dualboot Ubuntu 22.04.3 and Windows 11. My objective is to share the desktop information, images, documents, and downloads between both systems. The method I used was to create symbolic links of the local folders in Ubuntu so that they pointed to the location of the common disk between the 2 systems, and it worked perfectly, I achieved my objective.

The problem arose when I restarted the computer and the desktop referred to by the symbolic link located on the common disk did not load because this disk does not mount by default when the system starts. Instead, the contents of HOME appear on the desktop.

I solved the problem of mounting the disk when the system starts by copying the line that refers to the disk mounting inside the /etc/mtab file and pasting it into the /etc/fstab file.

However, the problem of loading the HOME contents instead of the desktop contents persists.

If you could give me a solution and also if there is a more efficient method to achieve my objective with having the information on a common disk for both OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First check whether your current symbolic links still point to a valid location on your windows drive. Probably this is the case.
- Then, you will need to correct a configuration file, such that it again is notified of the correct locations of your "special folders":

  - Open `~/config/user-dirs.dirs` in a text editor
  - Make sure each entry points to a valid symbolic link in your home directory, e.g. for the Desktop folder:

    ```
    XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
    ```

Comment: Thank you very much, following those steps I was able to find the solution.

Comment: If this answer resolved your question, then please show your appreciation by "accepting" it: click the checkmark next to the answer.